# Python convert dict of lists to dict of sets?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have:

`myDict = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]}`

I want:

`myDict = {'a': set([1,2,3]), 'b':set([4,5,6]), 'c':set([7,8,9])}`

Is there a one-liner I can use to do this rather than looping through it and converting the type of the values?

Comment: `myDict = {k: set(v) for k, v in myDict.items()}`, iteration is pretty much required

Comment: The one liner would *also* loop through it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to loop anyway:

```
{key: set(value) for key, value in yourData.items()}
```

If you're using Python 3.6+, you can also do this:

```
dict(zip(myDict.keys(), map(set, myDict.values())))
```

Comment: I like the zip, I went with a display of map as well but zipping didn't cross my mind

Comment: @ForceBru Are there any cases that won’t work on Python versions older than 3.6?

Comment: Any reason why we should prefer the zip version over the comprehension?

Comment: @Nae, no need to prefer the `zip` version: if the comprehension looks cleaner and more readable, then use the comprehension

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without looping anyway, but you can have the looping done in one line, with the following code:

```
myDict = {k:set(v) for k, v in myDict.items()}
```

This is basically traversing each item in your dictionary and converting the lists to sets and combining the key(str):value(set) pairs to a new dictionary and assigning it back to myDict variable.

Comment: To help readers understand your solution, consider including a short description of your code and how it solves the posted question

Answer (score 1):

You can use comprehension for it:

Basically, loop through the key-value pairs and create set out of each value for the corresponding key.

```
>>> myDict = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]}
>>> myDict = {k: set(v) for k, v in myDict.items()}
>>> myDict
{'a': {1, 2, 3}, 'b': {4, 5, 6}, 'c': {8, 9, 7}}
```

Comment: To help readers understand your solution, consider including a short description of your code and how it solves the posted question

Comment: Thanks @HenryWoody. I added the desciption!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `map` by mapping the values to type `set`

```
myDict = dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], set(x[1])), myDict.items()))
```

Or with either version of *dictionary comprehension* as well

```
myDict = {k: set(v) for k, v in myDict.items()}
myDict = {k: set(myDict[k]) for k in myDict}
```